# How to show OptionMenu() after cllongclick of any one listitems

Tags: android

I want to show the option menu on the longclick of any listitems as well as it should be shown automatically in the case of multiple selection from the listview.

Comment: Could you clarify what you're asking? "as well as it should be shown automatically in the case of multiple selection" does not make sense.

Comment: when we will use checkboxes to select multiple items

Comment: Try 'this.openOptionsMenu();'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, all you should have to do is set a listener and call the openOptionsMenu method.

```
getListView().setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        YourActivity.this.openOptionsMenu();
        return true;
    }
});
```

You should familiarize yourself with the methods available to [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/package-summary.html) and [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).